# Using np.log10 function on value from function-created list causes TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I am using the list `dlArr` created from `dl(z,rz)` in `mth(dlz)` but I get the below error which I can't resolve.

Error:

> TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type generator which has no callable log10 method

Code:

```py
def dl(z,rz):
    dl = (1+z) * rz
    return dl

dlArr= [(dl(z,rz) for z, rz in zip(zArr, rzArr))]

def mth(dlv):
    mth = 5 * np.log10(dlv) + 24
    return mth

mthArr = [mth(dlv) for dlv in zip(dlArr)]
```

Comment: I don't think you mean to have a list of length 1 containing a generator. `[(dl(z, rz) for z, rz in zip(zArr, rzArr))]` did you mean to have a list comprehension `[dl(z, rz) for z, rz in zip(zArr, rzArr)]`?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```py
dlArr= [(dl(z,rz) for z, rz in zip(zArr, rzArr))]
```

Is a list of a generator (the brackets indicate the generator)

Remove the brackets so it's a list comprehension:

```py
dlArr= [dl(z,rz) for z, rz in zip(zArr, rzArr)]
```